# Check if database connection can be etablished on CodeIgniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My application can be used with or without a database so I need to know if a database is correctly configured to show or hide functionalities which require a database.

How can I access to database config vars to check if they are filled?

Everything I found on the web requires to do a `$this->load->database();` so I can access to database vars from the `$this->db` object.

The problem is that if we do not have a database or if the database config file is not properly set, `$this->load->database();` will results in a PHP error:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Comment: Please tell me when you don't need database and need it based on what ? i guess you should put if in every event

Comment: Every time. On every page I need to do additional traitements if I have a database connection.

Comment: you can check database vars in construct method using `$this->db->username`, `$this->db->database` etc. It will return your DB settings. If this not work you may use hooks

Comment: As I said in my question, `$this->db->username` return error `Message: Trying to get property of non-object` since I have not do a `$this->load->database()` which returns a PHP error if connection could not be established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the 'db_debug' setting Off.

It is what triggers these messages in case of an error, but it's only there to help you debug, obviously.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. But page load is very slow when hostname is not responding. The only way I found to bypass this is to set the hostname to a string of one space because empty string seems to fallback on localhost.

Comment: I also need to add @ to hide PHP warnings `@$this->load->database();`